# Automatically remove document from the collection when array field becomes empty

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents which contains array fields with even triggers and when there are no more triggers left i want to remove this document. As i understand mongo doesn't have triggers support. Is there any way i can delegate this job to Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there is no triggers in mongo. So there is no normal way to do this with mogno. You have to use application logic to achieve this. One way would be to do cleaning every n minutes. Where you remove documents which have array of size zero. Another way (which I like a more) is after each update to the document, remove it if it has empty array.

Answer (score 1):

The only feature I know MongoDB provides to expire data is by using an expiration index.
[Expire data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Comment: Thanks, but TTL is not suitable in my case.